# Confusion using to_date function to confirm date format

Tags: oracle

```
select  to_date('07/09/14','yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
```

is returning `14-SEP-07`

I was expecting it to thrown an exception as the date and the format requested are not the same. Secondly we have slashes in the input date and hypen in the format.

Can someone tell me how to confirm if the input value is of the provided format.

Comment: I think that this only answers some of your question, but check out the official documentation on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: **`TO_DATE()`** only takes a string and convert it to a date/time in respect to the given format your provided. If it can't find the exact format, it will do its best to determine what could it be. Given you `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, Oracle deduces that the `07` is the year, and the `14` is the day ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132). You have to write your own function to throw an expected exception or the like to handle the issue, if there is any based on your functional requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEXP_LIKE` can somewhat do this.  Note, this is basic, since it would accept values like `2014-0-32`.  However, those insane values would fail in whatever you do next in your code, such as `to_date()`.

```
SELECT 'Yes, valid boss.' is_valid FROM DUAL
  WHERE regexp_like('07/09/14','^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$');

no rows selected
```

.

```
SELECT 'Yes, valid boss.' is_valid FROM DUAL
  WHERE regexp_like('2014-07-09','^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$');

IS_VALID
----------------
Yes, valid boss.
```

.

```
SELECT 'Yes, valid boss.' is_valid FROM DUAL
  WHERE regexp_like('2014-7-9','^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$');

IS_VALID
----------------
Yes, valid boss.
```

EDIT: and if you're into PL/SQL, you can do a regex match and throw your own exception ...

```
DECLARE
  v_is_valid INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO v_is_valid FROM DUAL
    WHERE regexp_like('07/09/14','^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$');
  IF v_is_valid = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error (-20400, 'Exception: date was given in the wrong format.');
  END IF;
END;
/

*
ORA-20400: Exception: date was given in the wrong format.
```

Comment: thank you very much Joshua. The regular expression helped me add the checks for -,/ and also the number of positions in the input date before i feed it to to_date for that mask. thax a million.

Answer (score 1):

`to_date` is relatively liberal in attempting to convert the input string using the provided format mask.  It generally doesn't concern itself with the specific separator character in the string or in the format mask-- your string could use dashes or slashes or, heck, asterixes if you wanted.  Of course, that can mean that you get unexpected results.  In this case, for example, the `date` that is created is in the year 7 (i.e. 2007 years ago).  That is a valid date in Oracle but it is highly unlikely to be the date you expect unless you're storing data about ancient Rome.

What, exactly, does it mean to you to "confirm if the input value is of the provided format"?  Depending on what you are looking for, you may want to use regular expressions.

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for pointing out about the separator characters and the regular expressions idea. By "how to confirm if the input value is of the provided format" i meant i wanted to_date to look for a date which is 2007-09-14 if the mask was yyyy-mm-dd or thrown an exception. Have to use regular expressions to make sure of that before i call to_date like joshua has shown below.

Answer (score 0):

[**`TO_DATE()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132) only takes a string and convert it to a date/time in respect to the given format your provided. If it can't find the exact format, it will do its best to determine what could it be. Given your `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, Oracle deduces that the `07` is the year, and the `14` is the day.

You have to write your own function to throw an expected exception or the like to handle the issue, if there is any based on your functional requirements.

So when you select the resulting date, the format that is displayed is actually based on your [**NLS_DATE_FORMAT**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm) system parameter, which gives your resulting date.